# Insert Trigger with check option on multiple tables view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with trigger on multiple tables view.

Let me explain:
I have 2 data tables with primary keys and table Event with many to many relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE Club
(
    name_of_club varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    adress varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Band
(
    name_of_band varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    members int NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE Event
(
    name_of_club varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    name_of_band varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        data date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Event PRIMARY KEY
    (
        name_of_club,
        name_of_band
    ),
    FOREIGN KEY (name_of_club) REFERENCES Club (name_of_club),
    FOREIGN KEY (name_of_band) REFERENCES Band (name_of_band)
)
```

Now I can add some values:

```
insert into Club (name_of_club, adress)
       values
       ('Big London Club', 'Londyn, Baker Street 12'),
       ('Espana Time', 'Barcelona, Diego 15'),
       ('Wwa', 'Warszawa, Sezonowa 82/14'),
       ('Szwalnia', 'Łódź, Piotrkowska 20/2');

insert into Band (name_of_band, members)
       values
       ('Arctic Monkeys', 5),
       ('Random Guys', 3),
       ('TILT', 10),
       ('Joke Time', 2);



insert into Event (name_of_club, name_of_band, data)
           values
           ('Big London Club', 'Arctic Monkeys', '2015-01-25'),
           ('Wwa', 'TILT', '2015-01-28'),
           ('Szwalnia', 'Joke Time', '2015-02-10');
```

Let's create the VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW Events AS

SELECT Club.name_of_club, adress, Band.name_of_band, members, data
FROM Event
JOIN Club ON Club.name_of_club = Event.name_of_club
JOIN Band ON Band.name_of_band = Event.name_of_band
```

Now I must create a trigger for INSERT operation.

1 * When inserting a row into view, I need to check if a row exists:

- YES -> display error
- NO -> go to point 2

2 * Check if there is a club and a band with the specified names on insertion.

- If yes, check if the information is
  correct and go to 3* .
- If something is wrong -> display error.

3 * When the row contains the data of the club and the band is not in the
   table, make-up base tables. At the end make-up Event table
   representing the many-to-many relationship. Now should be better.

Edit: points of trigger works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can be accomplished using INSTEAD OF TRIGGER, trigger should be like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsteadOfEventInsert ON Events INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name_of_club VARCHAR(50),
            @name_of_band VARCHAR(50),
            @data DATE,
            @members int

    SELECT  @name_of_club = name_of_club,
            @name_of_band = name_of_band,
            @data = data,
            @members = members
    FROM INSERTED

    IF NOT EXISTS(  SELECT  1 
                    FROM    Events 
                    WHERE   name_of_club = @name_of_club 
                    AND     name_of_band = @name_of_band 
                    AND     data = @data
                )
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Club WHERE name_of_club = @name_of_club)
            INSERT INTO Club VALUES(@name_of_club, @members)

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Band WHERE name_of_band = @name_of_band)
            INSERT INTO Band VALUES(@name_of_band, @members)

        INSERT INTO [Event] SELECT name_of_club, name_of_band, data FROM INSERTED
    END
END
```

I would recommend just adding an INT identity column for Club and Band instead of making name as primary key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code is very clear and quite understand it. I must think about it now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Example insert:

```
INSERT INTO Events values ('Test Club', 'Test Adress', 'Test Band', 5, '2015-01-01')
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsteadOfEventInsert ON Events INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name_of_club VARCHAR(50),
            @adress varchar(50),
            @name_of_band VARCHAR(50),
            @members int,
            @data date

    SELECT  @name_of_club = name_of_club,
            @adress = adress,
            @name_of_band = name_of_band,
            @members = members,
            @data = data
    FROM INSERTED

    IF NOT EXISTS(  SELECT  1 
                    FROM    Events 
                    WHERE   name_of_club = @name_of_club 
                    AND     adress = @adress
                    AND     name_of_band = @name_of_band 
                    AND     data = @data
                )

    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Club WHERE name_of_club = @name_of_club)
        INSERT INTO Club VALUES(@name_of_club, @adress)

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Band WHERE name_of_band = @name_of_band)
        INSERT INTO Band VALUES(@name_of_band, @members)
    END
    INSERT INTO [Event] SELECT name_of_club, name_of_band, data FROM INSERTED
END
```

It should look something like this?

Edit: it works ;)